# how can i update this Mobile Number field in firestore database any more update features

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I have fetched the data successfully and also i am routing that data also. now i am trying to update that touchableOpacity TextInput field back to firestore. the process i have done is correct or i am doing some thing messy please have a look at that it would be beneficial for me. the routing process {route.params.item.MOBILE_NO} as you can see. Thankyou

```
const ItemDetails = ({ route }) => {
const [phone, setPhone] = useState("")

    const UpdateNumber = (MOBILE_NO, updated) => {
        db.collection("Data").
        doc(MOBILE_NO.id)
        set(MOBILE_NO).then(() => updated(MOBILE_NO)).
        catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, paddingTop: 253, paddingLeft: 5 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 25 }}> Mobile : </Text>
            </View>

            <TouchableHighlight style={{ alignItems: 'flex-start', paddingLeft: 110, paddingTop:7 }}>
                <TextInput placeholder = "Mobile number" 
                value = {phone}
                onChangeText = {text => setPhone(text)}
                
                style={{ fontSize: 25, backgroundColor:'#f0f8ff',
                 borderRadius:10, width:'70%',height:30, }}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 25,  }}>{route.params.item.MOBILE_NO}
                    </Text>
                </TextInput>
            </TouchableHighlight>
            <Button onPress = {UpdateNumber()} title = "Update"/>
            </View>
)
}
```

Comment: Are you facing any issue doing this? If yes, please provide your error here.

Comment: where ?? plaase

Comment: Please look into this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask documentation on how to ask a good question.